# Call AngularJS RouteProvider Controller from Javascript window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

App.js:

```
angular.module('Note', []);
angular.module('MyProj', ['Note'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/note/viewNotes/:Id', {
        controller: 'viewNotesCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'web/modules/note/views/viewNotes.html'
    })
```

I want to call the 'viewNotesCtrl' from a pop-up that is typical javascript pop-up

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
```

ViewNotesCtrl.js

```
  $scope.showViewNotes = function () {
        //$window.open('/note/viewNotes/' + $scope.Id, 'width=500,height=400');
    }
```

But this is not working. Can anyone please suggest how can I call the ViewNotesCtrl using Javascript pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it like that.

If you want a specific url in your popup, then you will have to find that url and pass it as an argument to `window.open()`

But bear in mind that the new window will have to load everything from scratch and that is probably not desired.

I would recommend some "in page popup" like for example "Bootstrap modal" http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

For window you can define controller like `ng-controller` and the controller will bind to that view.